# Binding element 'params' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am getting error

> Binding element 'params' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Here is my code:

```
export default function Page({ params }) {
  const { slug } = params;
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{slug}</h1>
      <Link href="/">Home</Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Give it a type? We don't know what you expect for it. At a guess `{ params: { slug: string } }` but you should be in a position to determine that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to explicitly define the `any` type.

Like this

```
{ params }: any
```

Full solution

```
export default function Page({ params }: any) {
  const { slug } = params;
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{slug}</h1>
      <Link href="/">Home</Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is the worst solution. `any` should be avoided whenever possible. Or if that's your first solution, just don't use TS. `any` is an escape hatch from the type system. It's roundabout to add a type system only to disable it whenever it becomes even slightly (and trivially avoidably) inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution

```
export default function Page({ params }: { params: { slug: string }}) {
return (
    <div>{slug}</div>
  );
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes